# Two different listings at the same time

Tags: beamer, listings, overlays

I would like to show two different pieces of listings at the same time in a slide. With the following code the second listing only shows up at the end, while I would like it to alongside with the line 'int y = 20':

```
\begin{lstlisting}
    int x = 10; @\pause@
    int y = 20; @\pause@
    int z = 42; @\pause@
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{.5cm}
 \begin{onlyenv}<2->
  \begin{lstlisting}
     int next (int x)
  \end{lstlisting}
 \end{onlyenv}
\end{overlayarea}
```

The delimiters @ are used to escape inside a listing block.

Comment: Can you please convert your code fragments to a compilable MWE?